# Recycler view is not updated until you start scrolling

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm doing the chat. I can not make a message appear when I receive and send it. New messages appear only when I scroll this sheet. If you use the `scrollToPosition (0)` method, everything works. But in this case, the page will scroll **and when receiving** messages from the interlocutor, which is unacceptable. I've been dealing with this problem for probably a week, and I can not fix it. I will be happy with any help. I enclose the code:

**Adapter init:**

```
MessagesListAdapter<IMessage> adapter;
...
adapter = new MessagesListAdapter<IMessage>(user.getUser_id(), imageLoader);
```

**WebSocketListener(for message recieving)**:

```
webSocket.addListener(new WebSocketListener() {
            ...

            @Override
            public void onFrame(WebSocket websocket, WebSocketFrame frame) throws Exception {
                Log.i("fg", "onFrame");
                JSONObject data = new JSONObject(frame.getPayloadText());
                Log.i("fg", "data: " + data.toString());

                if (data.has("data")) {

                    switch (data.getString("type")) {
                        case "Text":
                            Log.i("fg", "type text");
                            MyMessage myMessage = new MyMessage(data.getString("user_id"), data.getString("data"),
                                    data.getString("login"), data.getString("unix_time"), data.getString("user_id"), data.getString("avatar"));
                            Log.i("fg", "before " + Integer.toString(adapter.getItemCount()));
                            adapter.addToStart(myMessage, true);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            break;
                        case "Location":
                            Log.i("fg", "type location");
                            MyLocationMessage myLocationMessage = new MyLocationMessage(data.getString("user_id"), data.getString("data"),
                                    data.getString("login"), data.getString("unix_time"), data.getString("user_id"), data.getString("avatar"));
                            Log.i("fg", "before " + Integer.toString(adapter.getItemCount()));
                            adapter.addToStart(myLocationMessage, true);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            break;
                        case "Photo":
                            Log.i("fg", "was here images");
                            MyImageMessage myImageMessage = new MyImageMessage(data.getString("user_id"), data.getString("data"),
                                    data.getString("login"), data.getString("unix_time"), data.getString("user_id"), data.getString("avatar"));
                            Log.i("fg", "before " + Integer.toString(adapter.getItemCount()));
                            adapter.addToStart(myImageMessage, true);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            break;
                    }
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, adapter.getItemCount());


            }
```

**Adapter:**

```
public MessagesListAdapter(String senderId, ImageLoader imageLoader) {
        this(senderId, new MessageHolders(), imageLoader);
    }

    /**
     * For default list item layout and view holder.
     *
     * @param senderId    identifier of sender.
     * @param holders     custom layouts and view holders. See {@link MessageHolders} documentation for details
     * @param imageLoader image loading method.
     */
    public MessagesListAdapter(String senderId, MessageHolders holders,
                               ImageLoader imageLoader) {
        this.senderId = senderId;
        this.holders = holders;
        this.imageLoader = imageLoader;
        this.items = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return holders.getHolder(parent, viewType, messagesListStyle);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //  Log.i("fg","onBindViewHolder position: " + Integer.toString(position));
        Wrapper wrapper = items.get(position);
        holders.bind(holder, wrapper.item, wrapper.isSelected, imageLoader,
                getMessageClickListener(wrapper),
                getMessageLongClickListener(wrapper),
                dateHeadersFormatter);


    }

    public int getMessagesCount(){
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++){
            Wrapper wrapper = items.get(i);
            if (wrapper.item instanceof IMessage) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // Log.i("fg", "position: " + Integer.toString(position));
        return holders.getViewType(items.get(position).item, senderId);
    }

 public void addToStart(MESSAGE message, boolean scroll) {
        boolean isNewMessageToday = !isPreviousSameDate(0, message.getCreatedAt());
        if (isNewMessageToday) {
            items.add(0, new Wrapper<>(message.getCreatedAt()));
        }
        Wrapper<MESSAGE> element = new Wrapper<>(message);
        items.add(0, element);
        notifyItemRangeInserted(0, isNewMessageToday ? 2 : 1);
        if (layoutManager != null && scroll) {
            layoutManager.scrollToPosition(0);
        }
    }
```

**ХML with message list:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.uncolor.aroundme.Dialog">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonLoadMore"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center|top"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/previous_messages"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrevMsgs"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <com.stfalcon.chatkit.messages.MessagesList
            android:id="@+id/messagesList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:paddingTop="30dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        </com.stfalcon.chatkit.messages.MessagesList>

    </FrameLayout>
```

I use this library [ChatKit for Android](https://github.com/stfalcon-studio/ChatKit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the problem is that onFrame method is running not in UI thread. This way you can apply changes in UI. You can try Handler here.

Comment: Can you show me example, please?  I am not sure that understand you right) Thanks!

Comment: You should learn that https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html

Comment: I have more small question. What I must insert in handler? Only adapter.notifyDataSetChanged or all code of onFrame method? Thanks!

Comment: runOnUiThread() helped me to fix the issue in my case

Answer (score -1):

English:

I have the same problem, my business is : viewpager+fragment; several of the fragments have a recyclerview, which needs to be scrolling before being displayed;
This situation is not necessarily present, but there is a high probability of it;
At the same time I have ruled out three possibilities:

1, the data source is the same list;

2, notifyDataSetChanged in the main thread;

3, the address of the recyclerview has not changed;

中文：

我有同样的问题，我的业务是一个viewpager+fragment；其中几个fragment中有recyclerview，显示的时候需要手动划一下才显示；

这种情况不是必现的，但有很大的概率出现；

同时我已经排除了三个可能性：

1、数据源是同一个list;

2、是在主线程进行的notifyDataSetChanged;

3、recyclerview的地址始终没变；